# how to get the value outof the function and use the value in another component using angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to get the "userIdFromToken" value out of the function and pass it to another component in angular typescript.
Note: I am newbie to Angular and TypeScript.
Here is my Typescript function which has the value i want to pass to another component

```
login(loginForm: NgForm){
    this.loginService.login(loginForm.value).subscribe(
      (response: any) => {
        this.auth.setRoles(response.user.role)
        this.auth.setToken(response.token)
        this.auth.setUserId(response.user.user_id)
        const userIdFromToken = response.user.user_id

        const usernameFromToken = response.user.username
        // this.foundUserName.emit(usernameFromToken)
        // this.foundUserId.emit(userIdFromToken)
        // console.log(usernameFromToken)
        // console.log(userIdFromToken)

        
        // return userIdFromToken
      }
    )
  }
```

Comment: If you need to pass value to child /parent component, use Input() /Output() https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs.